# How to add div element with image description to my "slick-img-slider" dynamically from my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

So I have a website with mostly images, that are all dynamically called from a JSON file, even the list of projects is generated through Javascript from JSON.

```
function populateMenuList() {
    data.Projects.forEach(i => {
        var listElement = $(`<li class="list-item" id="project-${i.id}" data-sari="${i.data}">${i.Title}</li>`)
        listElement.on("click", () => {setProject(i)})
        $("#project-list").append(listElement);
    });

}
```

```
<nav class="saris nav-wrapper row horizontalList">
      <!-- PROJECT LIST FROM JSON DATA -->
<ul id="project-list" class="cursor-pointer projectList projects">
<li class="list-item" id="project-1" data-sari="1">Project_1</li>
<li class="list-item" id="project-2" data-sari="2">Project_2</li>
<li class="list-item show" id="project-3" data-sari="3">Project_3</li>
<li class="list-item" id="project-4" data-sari="4">Project_4</li>
<li class="list-item" id="project-5" data-sari="5">Other artworks</li><
/ul>
    </nav>
```

So each project has images sliding so I added a "data" attribute for basically the problem I have. I would like a project description to appear when I click on project_1 for example. But as everything is embedded into a slider each time I put an object, I have no Javascript control over it to make an "on click " appear/disappear" for the dynamic menu elements.

I don't know if this is relevant, but this is the home page which calls the 1rst img of each project, and then from there onwards once I click on a (li)Project element then it is all dynamic. So I was wondering if I could also add the project description which is in the JSON file ${i.About}, but something seems to interfere and nothing shows up. So it's not a description per image but per project.

Hope it is clear, hope there is a simple way for this! thanks a lot!

```
    <section class="content-wrapper">

      <div class="gallery-wrapper slideshow-container">
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p1_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p2_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />

        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p3_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p4_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img id="gallery" src="./assets/img/p5_img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery picture" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden buttonLeft" aria-label="Previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
      <div class="hidden buttonLeft" aria-label="Next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the principle and the question. Do you want the description of a project to be displayed when you click on a Project present in the list..? Or the description of an image when you click on this image...?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So The description when I click on the list element. not on the images.